# Posição labels é alterada quando a janela é diminuida

Tags: javascript

Crio labels dinamicamente, e quando diminiu a janela a posição das labels alteram. Utilizei o position fixed, mas mesmo assim movem-se.

Exemplo :http://jsfiddle.net/zy6nLcgL/7/

```js
var txtmaxresistance=100;
 var maxtemp=100;
 var resolutionOhm=10;
    var resolutionTemp=10;
    var txtmintemp=0;
    var txtminresistance=0;

 var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

 var dernier_position_temp =new Array();
 var number_temp =new Array();
 
 var dernier_position_ohm =new Array();
 var number_ohm =new Array();

 for (var i = 1; i <= resolutionOhm; i++) {
  
  var distance = 400/resolutionOhm;  
  var y1 = 450;
  
  //si c'est la premiere ligne
  if(i==1){
   
   x1= 60+distance;
   dernier_position_ohm.push(x1);
   
        }else{
   x1 = ((dernier_position_ohm[i-2]+distance));
   dernier_position_ohm.push(x1);
  
  }
  
 
  var x2 = x1;
  var y2 =  470;
  
  var line = document.createElementNS( 
   "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
  line.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", x1);
  line.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", y1);
  line.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", x2);
  line.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", y2);
  line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black");
  line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "2");
  svg.appendChild(line);
  
 
  var number=Math.round(((txtmaxresistance-txtminresistance)/resolutionOhm)*i+txtminresistance);

  //push in array pour souver valeur (fichier SVG) 
  number_ohm.push(number);
  
  //creation labels
  var labeltemp = document.createElement("Label");
  labeltemp.style.left = x2-10+ "px";
  labeltemp.style.top = y2+5+ "px";  
  labeltemp.style.position='fixed';
  
  var number = document.createTextNode(number);
  labeltemp.appendChild(number);
    
  document.body.appendChild(labeltemp);
  
 }
```

```css
body,html,#dd,#svg1{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 width:98%;
 height:98%
}
    
#dd{
 position:absolute;
}

circle {cursor:move}

.cursor {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}


.cursor-h {
    position: relative;
 left: 60px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.cursor-v {
    position: relative;
 top:60px;
    width: 0;
    height: 400px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.tablemain{
 width:100%;
}



.tdgraph{
 width:50%;
 
}

.tdtableau{
 width:50%;
 position:relative;
}

button:hover {
 background:#fffff;
}

#btn:hover
{
 background-color: LightCyan;
}

label#lbl_souris {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: Cyan;
}

#demo{
  position: absolute;
  left:140px;
}

label#lbl_Temp{
 position: absolute;
 left:35px;
 top:35px;
 
}

#lbl_MinTemp{
 position: absolute;
 left:40px;
 top:450px;
}

#lbl_Ohm{
 position: absolute;
 left:470px;
 top:455px;
}

#lbl_MinOhm{
 position: absolute;
 left:60px;
 top:475px;
}

#labeltemp{
 position: fixed;
}


#div_textresolution{
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
 position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
    <table class="tablecourbe" border=1 align=center>
     <tr>
      <td><label for="checkcsv">
       ddfsfdsf
      </label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkcsv" value="csv" id="checkcsv" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><label>
               gdfgfdd
       </label></td>
      <td><input type=text name=txtnamefile id=txtnamefile required value=dsfsfs /></td>
      
     </tr>     
    </table>
    </fieldset>
   <center><label id="demo" class=alarm ></label></center>
   </td>
   
   <td class=tdtableau >
    
    <div class="cursor" >
     <div class="cursor-h"></div>
     <div class="cursor-v"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="dd">  
     <svg id="svg1" style=position:static>
      <g id=g>
      </g>   
     </svg> 
    </div>
    
    <label id=lbl_Temp><?php echo trad($f_lng,"Temp");?></label>
    <label id=lbl_MinTemp>0</label>
     
    <label id=lbl_Ohm><?php echo trad($f_lng,"Ohm");?></label>
    <label id=lbl_MinOhm>0</label>
                
                <div id=div_textresolution></div> 
    <svg x=0 y=0 width=530px height=500px fill=black >
     
     //horizontal
     <line title="Horizontal" x1=60 y1=460 x2=460 y2=460 stroke-width=2 stroke=black /> 

    </svg>
    
    <label id="lbl_souris"></label>
   </td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar css media query para reposicionar seus label quando o tamanho diminuir

```
/*normal*/
label{
    margin-top: 12em;
}
/*quando o width diminui de 765px eu reposiciono o section*/
@media screen and (min-width: 765px){
    label{
        margin-top: 3em;
    }
}
```